# Autolayout ambiguity with inequalities

Tags: ios, cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm confused about how Cocoa's Autolayout determines whether a layout is ambiguous. Here's a simple example:

[image: Layout]

The observed behavior is as follows. The spacers to the left and right of the green rectangle are always the same width. When you stretch the superview horizontally outwards, the spacers stick to 80 while the rectangle expands. When you shrink the superview horizontally, the rectangle sticks to 398 while the spacers shrink to 10, after which the rectangle continues to shrink. At no point is the layout labeled ambiguous by IB.

However, you'll notice that the horizontal layout is defined almost entirely by inequalities! From what I can see, when the rectangle has a width of > 398, there's no reason for the spacers to have a width of 80. They could have a width of anywhere from 10 to 80 and still satisfy each horizontal inequality. That sounds ambiguous to me, but IB clearly does not agree.

There must be some implicit rule I'm missing. Please help me out!

Comment: Look at the priorities for those constraints. You'll understand.

Comment: I don't understand. How is what I described not ambiguous? How do priorities affect inequality solutions?

Comment: Let's work with examples. Which two constraints do you think are ambiguous?

Comment: Spacer width <= 80, spacer width >= 10, and rect width >= 398 could be solved with spacer width 10, 25, 40, 80 — anything between 10 and 80. No?

Comment: Not if you want variable width on that one. With the current setting, the spacer width is going to be between 10 and 80, and will always be greater than 10.

Comment: Ok, so how does the inequality solver arrive at a value of 80 for the spacer, without any warnings, when the rect size is >= 398?

Comment: Did not understand what you meant by that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, when I stretch the superview horizontally to anything past 558 (that is, 398 + 80 + 80), the spacers stick to size 80 while the green rectangle expands to fill the remaining space. But why doesn't IB complain about constraint ambiguity in this case? After all, the inequalities could be satisfied by the spacers being size anything between 10 to 80. There's some rule that's allowing the constraints to be uniquely satisfied, but I don't know what it is. This confuses me because IB is usually *very picky* about ambiguity!

Comment: That's where priorities come in. The spacers *tend* to be more 80 than 10, while the green view *tends* to be greater than 398 instead of less than it. If the spacer's width tends to 80, and there's nothing limiting it from it going to 80, it will go to 80.

Comment: OK, but what rule prioritizes the spacer going to 80 vs. the rect going past 398, especially when the rect width has a higher priority? What am I missing here?

Comment: Didn't get you, please elaborate.

Comment: The width for the green rect has a constraint of >= 398, priority 750. The width for the spacer has a constraint of <= 80, priority 300. Let's say the total width of the superview is 800. Currently, IB would solve this as 80 + 640 + 80. Why isn't the solution 10 + 780 + 10? After all, 10 is still less than or equal to 80, satisfying the spacer width constraint. What causes the spacer to greedily expand to 80, versus the green rect expanding maximally on account of it having a higher priority?

Comment: The constraint that makes the spacer expand is the >=10 (priority 1000). The <=80 *limits* it from expanding further. The >=10 constraint has a higher priority, as you can see.

Comment: Setting the >= 10 constraint to priority 700 still results in the same behavior.

Comment: Again, you're mistaking which constraint makes the green view expand. It's the >=398 constraint,  priority 750.

Comment: If you actually put this view hierarchy in a window and, at runtime, invoke `[theRect.window visualizeConstraints:[theRect constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal]`, does that indicate the constraints are ambiguous and let you exercise the ambiguity? I suspect it will. So that just means that IB is failing to recognize and report the ambiguity. Also, is Add Missing Constraints in View enabled in IB? If so, then IB recognizes there's ambiguity but doesn't raise it to the level of an "issue".

Comment: It seems like @duci9y is saying ">=" actually means ">= and as big as you can make it, within your priority"?

Comment: @Benjohn Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @duci9y Heh – that's an enormously important thing to know! Nice one. I was assuming it almost meant the opposite… "greater is fine, but I'd prefer =, please". If you want the behaviour I assumed, you need a lower priority constraint that tries to pull things together – it gets broken, but satisfied as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Auto layout has, coincidentally, ambiguous documentation. Therefore, the behavior you observed from your application is technically undefined. Here is exactly what the documentation says:

> Constraints have a priority level. Constraints with higher priority levels are satisfied before constraints with lower priority levels. The default priority level is required (NSLayoutPriorityRequired), which means that the constraint must be satisfied exactly. The layout system gets as close as it can to satisfying an optional constraint, even if it cannot completely achieve it.

The requirements are therefore

> The layout system gets as close as it can to satisfying an optional constraint
>   Constraints with a priority of 1000 must be satisfied exactly
>   Higher priority constraints are satisfied before constraints with lower priority levels

However, as you have noticed
    What causes the spacer to greedily expand to 80, versus the green rect expanding maximally on account of it having a higher priority?

Auto layout does not define "close as it can" and "Higher priory constraints are satisfied before constraints" in a unambiguous manner.  The Auto layout documentation mentions these two dimensions: priority and closeness; but these documents do not say how the optimization of these dimensions interact.

With that being said, here is one theory of how auto layout could operate based on the fact that auto layout is probably a multi-variable linear decomposition solver.

---

Let's consider your corner cases

> 1. When you stretch the superview horizontally outwards the spacers stick to 80 while the rectangle expands
> 2. When you shrink the superview horizontally, the rectangle sticks to 398 while the spacers shrink to 10
> 3. after which the rectangle continues to shrink

---

These corner cases can be reduced to

- **Case A** - superview > 398+80+80   (Spacers fixed at 80, rectangle expands from 398)
- **Case B** - superview > 398+10+10   (Rectangle fixed at 398, spacers contract from 80 to 10)
- **Case C** - superview <= 398+10+10  (Spacers fixed at 10, rectangle contracts from 398)

---

Notice how the numbers never jump from case to case. There is a smooth connection from **Case A** to **Case B** in the spacers, going from 80 -> 80 at the critical points.  The same occurs for the rectangle from **Case B** to **Case C**.  The algorithm used by auto-layout always results in a smooth solution when dealing with critical points.

---